# WPF Design Time 'Page' Switching

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a custom WPF menu control (similar to a tab control, I suppose) using a ListView to hold the headers, which then can be clicked to switch to the appropriate page. The problem with this is, when I'm coding up the XAML for windows that use the control I can't see anything past the first page in the designer view.

Is there a way to let me switch the view within the Visual Studio designer?

Comment: Could you style the tab control to do what you're trying to accomplish instead?

Comment: That would be difficult to do; we have code that "knows" about certain blessed controls and handles switching the design-time view. Styling a TabControl would be easiest.

Comment: Would this work with wrapping the control template around the TabControl, though? I've got some nice abstractions around it that make it nicer for us to use

Answer (score 0):

If your `ViewModel` has something like a `SelectedTab` property that is bound to your custom menu control's `SelectedItem` dependency property, then you could change your design-time data (or your design-time `ViewModel`) to make that tab selected by changing the `SelectedTab` property appropriately.